# Cannot log into my Google account, with any app

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google-account

I cannot log into my Google account in any app, like Play Store or Google Map. Whenever I try this, I get an error stating (see figure below)

*Couldn't sign in


There was a problem communicating with Google servers.


Try again later*:

[image: screenshot]

My phone is not rooted. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'forgetting' the current WiFi network, and then reconnecting to it. If this does not work, then the Google servers may be under maintenance, and you may need to wait for a while. (From 30+ mins to 2+ days.)